# How to pass string to module variable definitions?

Tags: javascript, typescript, model-view-controller

I'm new to typescript and MVC, so I'm not even sure if I'm asking the right question. But I have functionally identical typescript files that are used for multiple search screens. So I'm trying to consolidate it to a single file, that takes the search screen name and area (strings) and takes off from there. Is there a way I can pass this information to the typescript file from the view?

Here's a little code of my typescript for context.

```
module HarSearch {
    const area = "";
    const searchScreen = "";
    const gridName = searchScreen + "SearchGrid";
    const searchGrid = $(`#${gridName}`);
    const gridOptionsStorageName =  searchScreen + "GridOptions";
    const filtersStorageName =  searchScreen + "SearchFilters";
    const filterFormName = "formFilters";
    var defaultGridOptions: kendo.ui.GridOptions;

    $(function(e) {
        var harSearchGridData = searchGrid.data("kendoGrid");
        KendoGridFunctions.resizeGrid(searchGrid, -25);
        defaultGridOptions = harSearchGridData.getOptions();
        loadSearchState();
    });

    // more functions...
}
```

The area and searchName values are what I'd like to be able to set.

**EDIT:** thinking about Paleo's advice below, I thought maybe only breaking the variables I need into it's own class might get me closer. So I've edited my code a bit, but I still need a way to set these variables.

```
class definitions {
    public static area = "";
    public static searchName = "";
}

module HarSearch {
    const area = definitions.area;
    const searchName = definitions.searchName;
    .
    .
    .
    // rest is the same
}
```

Comment: You could use a class or a function instead? (Notice: your "module" is a [_namespace_](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html).)

Comment: I tried that actually. I couldn't get it to work for my application though because I need to access a kendo grid, and when I change to a class I can't get that data anymore. Sorry, I forgot to mention that in my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing. It's not my ideal solution, but it works. I didn't end up breaking my variables into their own class. They're still inside the module. I added a script in my view to set global variables which are then referenced by the module, where my Model.SearchArea and Model.SearchName are just strings.

**VIEW**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        searchArea = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.SearchArea));
        searchName = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.SearchName));
    })
</script>
```

**TS File**

```
module Search {
    declare var searchArea: string;
    declare var searchName: string;
    var gridName: string;
    var searchGrid: JQuery;
    var gridOptionsStorageName: string;
    var filtersStorageName: string;
    const filterFormName = "formFilters";
    var defaultGridOptions: kendo.ui.GridOptions;

    $(() => {
        gridName = searchName + "SearchGrid";
        searchGrid = $(`#${gridName}`);
        gridOptionsStorageName = searchName + "GridOptions";
        filtersStorageName = searchName + "SearchFilters";

        var searchGridData = searchGrid.data("kendoGrid");
        KendoGridFunctions.resizeGrid(searchGrid, -25);
        defaultGridOptions = searchGridData.getOptions();
        loadSearchState();
    });

    .
    .
    .
    //more functions
}
```